# CRXI: Need help removing duplicate workorders, only showing the one with the highest sequenceID less than 900

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I've been struggling trying to figure out how to deal with duplicate work orders showing up on a report in Crystal Reports XI. Each work order has a sequenceID and I want to show the record that has the highest sequenceID < 900, and if there is duplicates that have a sequenceID higher than 900, show both the highest record with sequenceID < 900 and the records >= sequenceID 900.

Ex Output:

```
WorkOrderNumber            SequenceID
WO1234                        4
WO1234                        6
WO1234                        902

Output Desired:
WorkOrderNumber            SequenceID
WO1234                        6
WO1234                        902
```

Ex2. Output:

```
WorkOrderNumber            SequenceID
WO1234                        20
WO1234                        50

Output Desired:
WorkOrderNumber            SequenceID
WO1234                        50
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add 2 groups in your report:
1.) Workordernumber
2.) SequenceID

So your data is sorted by these fields.
Then we need to find the max sequenceIds for a work orders below 900 and above.

Then you could create 2 formulas to handle this:

1.) If sequenceID < 900 then sequenceID else 0

2.) If sequenceID >= 900 then sequenceID else 0

You would then get the max result of each formula based on the workordernumber group by adding a summary or also add this to your formulas above. You would then suppress the sequenceID group if it did not equal one of the max summary value formulas. You could handle this by adding a simple formula in the suppress condition formula.

Comment: Thank you! I will try this and let you know if I still have any questions.

Comment: Would I put the fields in both groups footers or the details section? Also which section would you put the max summary's? @APB_Reports

Comment: Hi Brody, The max summaries on the 2 formulas would go in the workordernumber group footer. You then suppress the detail section or sequenceID group based on these summaries. In your suppress code you can see these summary formulas.